# UICollectionView.frame doesn't change position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, frame

I'm writing this function inside my custom UIView that changes the position UICollectionView inside my ViewController:

```
-(void) lowerPictures {
    UICollectionView* collectionView = ((AlbumViewController*)_basicViewController).picturesCollectionView;
    float endPosition = collectionView.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height;
    CGRect endFrame = CGRectMake(collectionView.frame.origin.x, endPosition,collectionView.frame.size.width, collectionView.frame.size.height);
    collectionView.frame = endFrame;
}
```

From some reason my frame doesn't get changed, no matter what i do. any reason why ?

Comment: When you look at endFrame is it actually a different value than it is to start with?

Comment: Do you have autolayout constraints on your collectionView?

Comment: first reason come to my mind is _basicViewController is nil. Maybe you forget to set your customview's _basicViewController.

Comment: It sounds like you have auto-layout selected within IB. Setting the frames programatically won't override the constraints, rather you need to program the constraint values to change. Is this the case with Autolayout?

Comment: @averydev it was this f*cking auto layout.. i had no constraint and i actually checked it before few times, but once i've unchecked the auto layout check box it started to work

Comment: @JimTierney you're right, but i'm not able to remove them... i don't see any constraints in the IB